# Canvas contenteditable not working

Tags: html, image, canvas, html5-canvas, contenteditable

I created canvas as **contenteditable ='true'** and paste image from clipboard on top of the canvas. The image appeared beside the canvas not on top of the canvas as per image below. I get empty image when try to convert the canvas to image. This is because my canvas doesn't hold the image i paste earlier. How do I get the image?

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>

  function convert()
  {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    //ctx.fillRect(50,50,150,75);
    var theImage=document.getElementById("toImage");
    theImage.src=canvas.toDataURL();
  }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300 contenteditable='true'></canvas>
    <button type="button" onClick="convert()">Click</button>
    <img id="toImage" width=300 height=300>
</body>
</html>
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a canvas-related in-page editing host for contenteditable.  Such an editor would certainly not be drag-drop as canvas requires drawing commands.  Also you'll run into CORS problems if your source image is a local image that has been copied to the clipboard.  If you are **really, really, really ambitious** you can be the one to write the canvas in-page editor using the six api methods here:  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#editing-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contenteditable` attribute is for text-related HTML elements, and does nothing with the `<canvas>` element.

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) for details on `contenteditable`.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely true. Your MDN link shows: "In HTML5 any element can be editable" and that MDN page does not mention <canvas> being an exception. I guess, making a <canvas> contenteditable is just asking for trouble; indeed <canvas> is not for text, but for creating graphics with javascript (see eg. http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html). So, in fact I DO agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Canvas Element is not an exception to `contexteditable` properties the difference between the canvas element and other elements is that the text inside of the canvas tag is dealing only with what shows when the canvas element is not supported. and `contexteditable` by definition is dealing with the text inside the element tag not the canvas ctx context that youre actually looking for. you want to look for the draw image method on your canvas a demo can be found [on the w3Schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)